# Retrieving Data from Firebase Database after saving with Unique ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a possible way to retrieve for example all the e-mails of the registered Users stored in Firebase Database if they are saved with their unique ID?
For example

```json
Users:
  -joj25okwev
    -E-mail: aaa@gmail.com
  -iergh234590
    -E:mail: bbb@gmail.com
etc..
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the emails from your firebase database, you can loop through your nodes and get all the values in `email` node in an array.

In code it looks something like this:

```java
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                     //array  will have all the emails in it
                        array.add(ds.child("E-mail").getValue(String.class));

                }
//code to display those emails using adapater
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        // Ref is correct databaseReference to your database
        Ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, though i have a question. To access the child ("E-mail") don't i have to access the previous child which is the unique id somehow?

Comment: No, `Ref` can be written as, `DatbaseReference Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");`

Comment: @ChristopherVradis did you try the code and does it work as expected?

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It worked flawlessly =)